# HP ML310e Update firmware IP v1.4 - Error

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, update, firmware

I'm trying to update firmware via the HP intelligent provisioning but it keeps returning with the error 'unable to connect to update server'. Pretty sure the router/fw is OK. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who knows? *(are you posting from the same network?)*

Verify your network settings...

It could be your Intelligent Provisioning version. Versions before 1.5 were crappy. You can [upgrade it manually](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5219984).

Firmware via Intelligent Provisioning isn't great. You do have the option of downloading the [Service Pack for ProLiant](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) to run updates. Or, to be quicker, you can just download the specific firmware updates you need (BIOs, RAID, NIC) from HP's support site.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, working from the bootable ISO's seems to be the way forward.